# C Extract Infix (char array) and cast to int

Tags: c

Given a string/char array e.g :

```
99+(88-77)*(66/(55-44)+33)
```

How do I extract the numbers and operators?

I would like to store them into two stacks a and b each containing number and operators only.

I am not sure on the logic, I was thinking of scanning each char in the char array, adding the char (number) into another char, until it meets an operator. Then I go to the char(number) and concatenate the string.

Is there a better way to do this, preferabbly without external libraries?

Comment: Your thinking seems sound. Scanning character by character, and checking the type (digit or non-digit) is the usual way to do it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That means my temp array to store the number should be at least the size of the my string I'm scanning, and each time I meet a non-digit, I should convert what is in the temp array to a inte.g if it contains ['1','2','3'] i should convert it to 123, then clear the temp array and repeat? is this a proper way?

Comment: Yes that's a proper (and the most common I would argue) way to do it. But remember the standard library functions for integer conversions (like e.g. `strtol`) expects the source to be a null-terminated string (so you need to append `'\0'` at the end of the array). Oh, and you don't need to "clear" it, just overwrite and remember to add the terminator.

Comment: Are you using C or C++ ?

Comment: i am on c, currently trying to solution from the comments and without using external libraries and functions like strlol @RohanKumar

Comment: Hmm, let me modify my answer without strtol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you can try using `strtol` for scanning integers from input string. I tried the suggested approach and it seemed to work for me for the provided test case. I haven't tested this for corner cases, but this should give you better idea of what users in comments are saying:

```c
int main() {
    char input[30] = "99+(88-77)*(66/(55-44)+33)";
    // Initialize Stack Indices
    operandStackIndex = 0;
    operatorStackIndex = 0;

    // Our markers for strtol()
    char *pStart = input;
    char *pEnd;
    long ret;

    while ((ret = convertStringToLong(pStart, &pEnd, 10)) > 0) {
        operandStack[operandStackIndex++] = ret;
        pStart = pEnd;
        while (isOperator(*pStart)) { // Check whether character it '+','-','/','(',')','*'..
          operatorStack[operatorStackIndex++] = *pStart;
          pStart++;
        }
    }

    printf("Operand Stack:\n");
    for (int i = operandStackIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        printf("%d\n", operandStack[i]);

    printf("Operator Stack:\n");
    for (int i = operatorStackIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%c\n", operatorStack[i]);
}
```

Here is simple implementation for `convertStringToLong` method(alternative to `strtol`):

```c
long convertStringToLong(char* pStart, char** pEnd, int base) {
    long num = 0;
    while (isDigit(*pStart)) {
        num = num * base + (*pStart - '0');
        pStart++;
    }
    *pEnd = pStart;
    return num;
}
```

When I ran this, I was able to see expected output:

```
Operand Stack:
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
Operator Stack:
)
+
)
-
(
/
(
*
)
-
(
+
```